# Usage of or operator in php?

Tags: php, logical-operators

The following code:

```
  $result = (false or true);
  echo("With extra parentheses: ".($result?"true":"false"));
  $result = false or true;
  echo("<br />With no parentheses: ".($result?"true":"false"));
```

generates the output:

```
With extra parentheses: true
With no parentheses: false
```

I do not understand why.  Shouldn't php evaluate `$result = false or true;` by first testing `false` and then, since it isn't true, going on to evaluate `true`?

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `or` operator has a weaker precedence than the assignment operator. What really happens in the second case is `($result = false) or true`, so the part `or true` really has no effect.

The assignment operator yields the assigned value as its result, `false` in this case. Think of the assignment operator as an ordinary binary operator that yields a result (like `+`, `<` and `or`), with the only difference that it has a side effect.

If you want to avoid the parentheses, you can swap `or` for `||`, which has a stronger precedence.

Always be careful when using the English versions of the logical operators, because their precedence is different.